# How do you manage adding new attributes on existing objects when using firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I have an app using React + Redux and coupled with Firebase for the backend.

Often times, I will want to add some new attributes to existing objects. 
When doing so, existing objects won't get the attribute until they're modified with the new version of the app that handles those new attributes.

For example, let's say I have a `/categories/` node, in there I've got objects such as this :

```
{
   name: "Medical"
}
```

Now let's say I want to add an `icon` field with a default of `"`

Is it possible to update all categories at once so that field always exists with the default value?

Or do you handle this in the client code?

Right now I'm always testing the values to see if they're here or not, but it doesn't seem like a very good way to go about it. I'd like to have one place to define defaults.

It seems like having classes for each object type would be interesting but I'm not sure how to go about this in Redux.

Do you just use the reducer to turn all `categories` into class instances when you fetch them for example? I'm worried this would be heavy performance wise.

Answer (score 0):

Any write operation to the Firebase Database requires that you know the exact path to the node that you're writing.

There is no built-in operation to bulk update nodes with a path that is only partially known.

You can either keep your client-side code robust enough to handle the missing properties, or you can indeed run a migration script to add the new property to each relevant node. But since that script will have to know the exact path of each node to write, it will likely first have to read/query the database to determine those paths. Depending on the number of items to update, it could possibly use multi-location updates after that to update multiple nodes in one call. E.g.

```
firebase.database().ref("categories").update({
  "idOfMedicalCategory/icon": "newIconForMedical",
  "idOfCommercialCategory/icon": "newIconForCommercial"
  "idOfTechCategory/icon": "newIconForTech"

})
```

Comment: I'm leaning more towards the robust code approach. I feel like a good way to handle this would be to have classes for each entity that'd be single points of failure. You could just initialise things in constructor, as well as being able to add functions/related logic in a single place that's reusable everywhere. But I'm still worried about the performance cost of such a solution. The reducer would have to create new class instances for each of the entities when fetching. Any thoughts on that ?